# Passing file name in youtube-dl post-process script without file extension suffix

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, youtube-dl

The documentation for [youtube-dl](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#readme) says I can run a post-process command with the `--exec` option.

Using Windows, here is an example I have tried:

```
youtube-dl --exec "ffmpeg -i {} -ac 2 -c:a libfdk_aac -cutoff 20000 -afterburner 1 -vbr 0 {}.m4a" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sw9DlMNnpPM
```

Note that `{}` passes the file name to the post-process command. For example `filename.webm`.

The problem is that `{}` includes the file extension.

How can I pass the file name to the post-process command without the file extension?

For example, if I were to convert the video, I would rather avoid getting an output name like `filename.webm.m4a`. Needless to say, I would rather want `filename.m4a`.

Comment: You can't pass filename without extension, because `youtube-dl` always writes .ext in output names. However, please note that encoding  audio that has been already encoded means that you are LOWERING final quality :-) 
So, use `youtube-dl -x --audio-format m4a  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sw9DlMNnpPM`, beacause there are no chances to get better results  in post-processing:-)

Comment: Sure perhaps this was a bad example. The point was just to show how to use the exec option. The problem is still the same.

Comment: ok, no way to pass filenames without extensions!